# Determining name of variable referencing new instance inside initialize

Tags: ruby, class, instance-variables

I can have a class announce its name whenever an instance is created like:

```
class Klass
    def initialize
        puts "#{self.class} instance created"
    end
end

instance = Klass.new #=> Klass intance created
```

How can I have the instance name announced from the class initializer? something like:

```
class Klass
    def initialize
        puts "#{self.class} instance #{self.instance} created"
    end
end

jacksaw = Klass.new #=> Klass instance "jacksaw" created
```

Comment: Would [`#object_id`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-object_id) meet your needs?

Comment: Your code is invalid.

Comment: @sawa - ah...because of the quotes?  Thanks. Will edit.

Comment: @pjs - I don't really have needs (besides coffee), just learning atm - thanks.

Comment: Not because of the quotes. Because of `Class`.

Comment: Aha - syntax highlighting has spoiled me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible. First, `Klass.new` will be created. Then, a local variable `jacksaw` will be assigned to it. At the moment of the creation of the instance, it cannot tell what local variable it will be assigned to.

Comment: There after the initialization of an object of class `Klass`, how you you identify what variables reference it? (local, instance, global alike)

Comment: Use `local_variables`, etc. to get the list of variables within the scope. Then, compare the `eval`ed value (or `local_variable_get`) of each of them with the object in question.

Comment: Note that `local_variable_get` is new as of Ruby 2.1 (not present in 2.0).